# GPUImageView with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, gpuimage

I am trying to use GPUImageView in an iPhone app with Auto Layout. I tried something like:

```
_imageView = [[GPUImageView alloc] init];
[self addSubview:_imageView];
[_imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];    
_gpuImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
[_gpuImage addTarget:_imageView];
[_gpuImage processImage];
```

The GPUImageView does not seem to be visible when I build and run the project.

If I remove all the Auto Layout constraints and initialize _imageView with initWithFrame, it is clearly visible. So, I am wondering if GPUImageView works with Auto Layout? Do I need to do something more to make it visible?

Update: GPUImage was installed via cocoa pods (~ 0.1.4). I am not sure if there were any new updates to the project that I missed.

Comment: Perhaps the constraints you're using have some problem?

Comment: I should have mentioned this before - with the exact same constraints, when I replace GPUImageView with a UIImageView, it seems to display the image correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're probably seeing is that `UIImageView` has an `intrinsicContentSize`, but `GPUImageView` does not. This means that without any width/height constraints, a `UIImageView` will display the image at its normal size, but not so with `GPUImageView` (depending on your other constraints, it could have a 0 width/height).

You can either add additional constraints on the `GPUImageView` to constrain its width and height to match what you expect, or you can subclass `GPUImageView` and implement `intrinsicContentSize` to return whatever you expect it to be. (It doesn't implement this normally because in general it can't determine a reasonable size would be; it renders to whatever size you make the view.)

Comment: That was it. I had constraints on the upper bound for width/height but not on the lower bound. Thanks!